# Does LinkedBlockQueue get the lock while calling await?

Tags: java, concurrency

I found following source code in `LinkedBlockingQueue`

```
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E x;
        int c = -1;
        final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
        final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
        takeLock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            while (count.get() == 0) {
                notEmpty.await();
            }
            x = dequeue();
            c = count.getAndDecrement();
            if (c > 1)
                notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            takeLock.unlock();
        }
        if (c == capacity)
            signalNotFull();
        return x;
    }
```

The `await` method release the lock and after it is signaled, in while loop again, seems it does not have the lock. And in `notEmpty<Condition>` it specifies that `IllegalMonitorStateException` would be thrown if not holding the lock during calling `await`.

This confused me.. Does it hold the lock or not eventually?

Comment: It holds the lock as soon as `await()` returns. Standard behaviour similar to `Object.wait()`. Read the documentation instead of saying "it seems". That's years old JDK code and you're claiming it's fundamentally broken. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 0):

of course It holds the lock.to judge whether the data can be token from queue, it uses loop.
when the queue is still empty,it should await again until it`s notified and the queue` count is not zero .